# Adding javascript in the main menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu

I am trying to insert `javascript:void(0)` into the Wordpress menu but it modifies the link to `http://javascript:void(0)`.

Is there a way to make the menu hold my original JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? A better way would be to put an event handler in a `.js` file and give the `<a>` an `href` of `#`.

Comment: Well I have a template that uses a accordion menu, but i don't want any links for the parent node.. it seems # works.. weird because I tough I tried that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to search about this " wp_nav_menu( $args ); " WordPress function or

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

Menu attributes are escaped before they're rendered and it's the reason why javascript is stripped off in your menus.

@Ref https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L146

You can easily overcome this by overriding `Walker_Nav_Menu` class in your `functions.php`

This doesn't fix your menus in WP-Admin escaping the javascript. You can still use `#` as your url and then replace it with `javascript:void(0)` by using:

```
if ( !is_admin() ) add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'javascript_void_attr'), 10, 3 );

    function javascript_void_attr( $atts, $item, $args ){
        if ( isset($atts['href']) && $atts['href'] == '#' ){
            $atts['href'] = 'javascript:void(0)';
        }
        return $atts;
    }
```

Comment: great suggestion. Just a heads up to anyone using this snippet, there is an error in your code, it should be:

`if ( !is_admin() ) add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'javascript_void_attr', 10, 3 );`

Notice, no `)` after javascript_void_attr